# R markdown: download a html table to an excel file

Tags: html, r, markdown, r-markdown, kable

I have a R markdown where I built a table and I want to add the option to download the table to a excel file.

```
kable(MyTable) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed", 
  "responsive")) %>%
  scroll_box(width = "900px", height = "500px")
```

Comment: Your question is not about `knitr` or `kableExtra`, it's about `shiny` and handling file downloads. Take a look at [`shiny::downloadHandler`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/download-file.html).

Comment: The point is that we do not want to use a shiny app but a r markdown html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could always try using `DT::datatable` to get export buttons

```
MyTable %>%
  DT::datatable(
    extensions = 'Buttons', 
    options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip', 
                   buttons = c('excel', "csv")))
```

Comment: small remark,specifying which buttons should appear seems to require a list, not a vector:  `..., buttons = list("excel", "csv")`

Comment: I got a CSV button only, and nothing happens when I click it.